# Get event when user sends deep link on Whatsapp

Tags: whatsapp, deep-linking, branch.io

We're using Branch.io deep links.

We want to know when the user actually sends these deep links via Whatsapp.

Is there a way to know that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Alex from Branch.io here: this feature isn't available directly. However, you should be able to get fairly close using our [webhooks feature](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/webhooks/overview/) combined with [custom events](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/user-value-attribution/guide/ios/#custom-event-tracking). Just set a custom event for when a user shares a link via Whatsapp, and then set a webhook to use that event as criteria.